# Run PHP script when clicking on a image

Tags: php, html, raspberry-pi, gpio

So i just got my new raspberry pi in the mail and have been playing around with it for a bit.
Now, i want to be able to turn a LED on using a PHP code.
Let's say i got the following image:
`<img src="images/On.png">`
How can i make it so that when i click on that button, it runs the following PHP code without going to a different page?

```
system ( "gpio mode 7 out" );
system ( "gpio write 7 1" );
```

I already tried the following using a button, which worked:

```
<?       
if ($_POST['submit'])  
{ 
    system ( "gpio mode 7 out" );
    system ( "gpio write 7 1" );
} 
if ($_POST['submit2'])
{
    system ( "gpio mode 7 out" );
    system ( "gpio write 7 0" );
} ?>
<form method="post" action=""> 
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="On">
<input type="Submit" name="submit2" value="Off">
</form>
```

But now i'd like to have this with an image, but the same code doesn't seem to work that way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "without going to a different page" => you should take a look at ajax and javascript in general. It allows to fire a request in background.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's `$.ajax`

Just give the `img` an `id` and you can do something like this: (example)

```
$("img#light-on").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "light-on.php",
    data: {lighton: "true"},
    success: function(){
      $("p.status").html("The light is on!");
    }
  });
});
```

You then have to just run the same thing for `img#light-off` and go to `light-off.php`.

You need to load jQuery in like this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

and then run the code in a seperate `script`:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("img#light-on").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "light-on.php",
        data: {lighton: "true"},
        success: function(){
          $("p.status").html("The light is on!");
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. [this is my current code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wUSSb3LW)

Comment: Have you included jquery? @linuxfreak23

Comment: [I've tried that aswell](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6qXwih10) , But it still won't turn on when i click on the image.
And the PHP script is working when i try to launch it manually.

Comment: Try this: http://pastebin.com/dMeY1hqz @linuxfreak23 Wrap it in `$(document).ready(` and make sure that the `script` stuff loads just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Still won't work. Not sure if it helps, but [here's](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=97XvxUaD) the entire code for the webpage, and [here's](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=eyU7TGgW) the code inside light-on.php

Comment: You haven't closed your `</script>` tag! @linuxfreak23

Comment: Oh wow, that fixed it, thanks!
Though, i only removed it after your last script, so don't worry, it wasn't all for nothing! :)
Thanks man, helped me out alot!

Comment: No worries glad I could eventually help haha sorry it took so long! @linuxfreak23

Comment: No problem, wouldn't 've figured it out without you!